# how to setup sbt configure in multi-project to run testng test

Tags: sbt, testng

I have a sbt multi-project setup, the project structure is something like the following

project parent 
    | 
    |-- Client 
    |  
    |-- Server

The parent project is a virtual project. The project/MyBuild.scala file is something like this

```
  import sbt._
  import Keys._
  object MyBuild extends Build {
      lazy val root = Project(id = "parent", base = file(".")) aggregate(server, client)
      lazy val server = Project(id = "server", base = file("server"))
      lazy val client = Project(id = "client", base = file("client")) dependsOn( server )
  }
```

The client and server are two independent projects with testng test setup and they are all working independently.

To run testng, I am using the testng interface plugin   "sbt-testng-plugin", which needs to specify testng test suite config xml.

On both client and server's build.sbt file, I have specified

```
testNGSuites := Seq(  "src/test/resources/testng.xml")
```

so that testng can find the testng.xml to run the tests.

In parent project, if I type

sbt compile

it compiles all the sub projects (client and server) separately. this works fine.

but if I type,

sbt test

the parent project sbt trying to run the testng tests, but fail out as it can't find the file

```
 src/test/resources/testng.xml
```

in parent project. Since parent is just a virtual directory, and doesn't have

```
 src/test/resources/testng.xml
```

therefore the test fails.

Now my question is how can I configure the settings to allow the sub-projects as well as parent project to run tests ?

I was thinking, if I can somehow set the settings in something like this in the sub-projects

```
 testNGSuites := Seq( base +  "src/test/resources/testng.xml")
```

so the testNGSuites is absolute to the sub-project rather to the parent project.

But since I am just started with sbt, I am not sure how to get the "base" path in sbt.

I tried with baseDirectory, but it's a setttingkey not the value itself.

Any help would appreciate.

thanks